# Jacob's Ladder Possible Circuit

Tags: diodes, circuit-design

The following circuit

[image: circuit]

has D1 which is a diode, and then D2 which I believe is another diode.  I think that the diodes are there to simply act like a flood gate type thing where they are controlling and making sure the circuit does short circuit.  Which would be the purpose of D1, but D2, I don't have an educated guess on it.  What would their function be in this circuit?

Comment: That's the schematic of a microwave oven. 3 is the magnetron tube. 3 is a diode itself, D1 is an antiparallel diode to make the transformer deliver AC, thus avoiding saturation. D2 is a voltage limiter for C, as Tr and C are a series resonator.

Comment: Thanks. (Don't forget that can be answer @Janka)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the schematic of a microwave oven. 3 is the magnetron tube. It's anode is tied to GND. That's one of the rare cases where GND has a positive potential against other parts of the circuit. The mounting inside the oven is much simpler that way.

Because a magnetron tube is a diode itself, the circuit needs the antiparallel diode D1. A transformer has to deliver AC, it would saturate if there was a DC component. Instead of using a rectifier bridge, and instead of throwing away the energy of one half wave, the circuit also acts as a voltage-doubler. That's the purpose of C, which is a series resonator together with the secondary main winding of Tr. The purpose of D2 is limiting the voltage over C to avoid C fail miserably (it could explode on overvoltage.)